# How to make a conditional logic using URL query in Next.JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to figure out how to create conditional logic based on a URL query.

In the example below, I'm trying to say Hello to Kátia Fantes dynamically when she accesses localhost:3000/katia-fantes.

How can I do that?

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const ClientDashboard = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { clientId } = router.query
  const KF = { 'clientId': 'katia-fantes' }

  if (KF) {
    return <h1>It's Katia</h1>;
  }
  return <p>Page not found. Sorry</p>;


}

export default ClientDashboard
```

Comment: Make sure the file is called `[clientId].js` https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: Also `if(kf)` doesn't make any sense. Consider using `if(clientId)` instead?

Comment: Yes, the file is called `[clientId].js` and I changed `if(kf)` to `if (clientId)` but... how to show "It's Katia" only for a specific URL path like e.g /katia-fantes?

Comment: `if(clientId === 'katia-fantes')`?

Comment: Genius! hehe Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To add to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68936029/how-to-make-a-conditional-logic-using-url-query-in-next-js#comment121833911_68936029),

if your use case is only for `katia-fantes`, then fine. if not, it is better to generalise the logic.

```
const { clientId } = router.query
const KF = { clientId }

  if (KF.clientId) {
    let client = KF.clientId.split('-')[0]
    client = client[0].toUpperCase() + client.splice(1)
    return <h1>It's {client}</h1>;
  }
  return <p>Page not found. Sorry</p>;
```